# Where can I find tutorials for Inkscape?

Tags: tutorial, inkscape

Where can I find tutorials for Inkscape?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following are a few that I found while doing a [quick search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=inkspace+tutorials&go=&form=QBRE&filt=all):

- [the InkspaceTutorial Weblog](http://inkscapetutorials.wordpress.com/)
- [Inkscape: Guide to a Vector Drawing Program](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/index.php)
- [screencasters.heathenx.org](http://screencasters.heathenx.org/)

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 5):

Within Inkscape itself, under Help -> Tutorials.

Comment: I looked at the Calligraphy tutorial before, which was nice.

Answer (score 2):

Spanish tutorials in [www.cursorlibre.com](http://cursorlibre.com)